# Unpacking a tuple within a list using spaCy's char_span

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, iterable-unpacking, spacy-3

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
TRAIN_DATA = {'here is some text': [('1', '4', 'entity_label')], 'here is more text': [('2', '7', 'entity_label_2')], 'and even more text': [('1', '4', 'entity_label')]}
```

I'm trying to convert this to the format required for spaCy's NER model, using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA: # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)

db.to_disk("train.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

It yields `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

When I try something slightly different:

```
nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for body, [(entities)] in TRAIN_DATA.items():
    doc = nlp(body)
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in entities:
        span = doc.char_span(int(start), int(end), label=label, alignment_mode='contract')
        ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents
    db.add(doc)
    db.to_disk("train.spacy")
```

It yields the same error. When I remove the tuple and list notation (i.e. `for body, entities...` vs `for body, [(entities)]`) I get expected 2, got 3 instead of expected 3 got 2...

I've tried troubleshooting by unpacking the tuple manually (i.e. `for i in entities.split(", ") print (i)`, and that seems to find all the values in the tuple, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The data sample you give at the start of your question is not in a valid format - you're missing a closing bracket after the second set of annotations. Regarding the error, you would get that if you had an annotation without a label for some reason. Your initial code looks fine, I think something is wrong with your data. Change your code to print the data before unpacking it and check that it's formatted right.

Comment: I will say it's weird to structure this as a dict - normally you would want this to be a list of tuples like `("my sentence", [(0, 1, "label")])`

Comment: @polm23 the missing bracket was a typo - thanks for pointing that out.